# page reloads and do not shows any content for routes "/places/new" and "/places/:id", secondly returns value as undefined or null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

page reloads and do not shows any content for routes "/places/new" and "/places/:id", secondly returns value as undefined or null
feels like issue is with mongoose find by id. when find by id function is ran then the issue starts again

```js
app.get("/places", function(req, res){
    place.find({}, function(err, places){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.render("places", {places : places});
        }
    });
    
});

app.post("/places",function(req, res){
    var name = req.body.placeName;
    var image = req.body.imgUrl;
    var description= req.body.description;
    var newPlace = {name: name, image : image, description : description};
    place.create(newPlace, function(err, newPlace){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.redirect("places");
        }
    })
});

app.get("/places/new", function(req, res){
    res.render("add-form");
});

app.get("/places/:id", function(req, res){
   place.findById(req.params.id, function(err, newPlace){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
         }
        else{
            res.render("show", {place : newPlace});        
         };
    });
 });
```

[image: code image][image]

Comment: You seem to have a relative path for the `./style.css`. That way, for `/places` it'll load `/places/style.css`. Make it absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you mention express, you should serve static files with express:

"For example, use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory named public. Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory:

```
app.use('/places/new', express.static('public'))
```

so save you add-form file in public folder: public/add-form.html

then get in ipaddress:port/places/new/add-form.html

source  [static-files-in-express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#serving-static-files-in-express)